# Oauth 2.0 Server and Requests library for PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, oauth

i'm learning about Oauth 2.0 library.
I read something about Oauth 2.0 Server [here](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/)

And after i looked for Oauth 2.0 Server for CodeIgniter in github.com/grasses/codeigniter-oauth2-server

That which i need it's to simulate obtaining authorization for access in a server that contains some api. Fistly i simulate this in command line:

```
curl -u testclient:testpass http://localhost/token.php -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

After i got the token, I ran this command to get access for resources:

```
curl http://localhost/resource.php -d 'access_token=MY_TOKEN'
```

The response was ok and i could access on the resource.

All that i need is to know if it exists a way to implement a client request with [Requests library](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests) making a token request to Oauth 2.0 Server. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It'd be great if you made some effort in implementing these requests with library of your choice and post code examples, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve